# html для сенсорного экрана

Tags: css

Есть ли какой-нибудь аналог `CSS` селекторов `div:hover`, `div:active` для тач-экранов?

Comment: див:телепат_ховер и div:active, потому что active он и в Африке active
а вот как угадать палец над элементом я хз

Comment: что-то я не нашел такого, можете написать не на транслите?

Comment: Это автор шутит так, он не знает как отловить ховер на мобильных девайсах. Да и как его отловить, вы как думаете?

Comment: @u_mulder вы имеете ввиду, что на них мышки нет? Это да, но почему-то когда я ставлю тень по hover, при нажатии на айфоне она появляется.

Comment: Если Вы подключите мышку на моб устройство, то ховер будет работать, а тач это не мышка и команды у него другие, да и не предусмотрен там этот наворот, зачем он Вам, когда в это место нажмут и все, если Вам нужно создать видимость нажатия, то используйте :focus

Answer (score 1):

На сенсорных экранах `:hover` выступает как обработчик нажатий, а `:active` как обработчик задержки.